# Where is the source code of dartaotruntime

Tags: flutter, dart

I try find source code of dartaotruntime, but there is no blog or document about this.

I try search from dart sdk, but there is no BUILD.gn rule to build this file.

Comment: `I try find source code of dartaotruntime, but there is no blog or document about this`. You correctly noted this. It is impossible to find anything interesting in the official Dart blog.

Comment: As i've linked in my answer, there is the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are searching for is the `dart compile` Code.
It is located [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1c571a12fa1d4b13b363546360dbf5ff765bdf4e/pkg/dartdev/lib/src/commands/compile.dart)

Answer (score 0):

`dartaotruntime` (aka `dart2native`) source code is located in the `dart-lang` repo:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dev/pkg/dart2native/lib/dart2native.dart